# PayPal Smart Button transaction not charging after 'approval'

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

After spending a full day on this *dangerous* thing, I can't understand how a transaction show APPROVED, I get an **order ID**, but there is no charge (not for buyer or receiver).
I am on live environment after tested on sandbox successfully.

So the code is long but basically on the server side we first create the transaction:

```
                  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
                        request.prefer("return=representation");
                        request.requestBody({
                          intent: 'CAPTURE', //CAPTURE
                          purchase_units: [{
                            amount: {
                              currency_code: currency,
                              value: finalPrice
                            },
                            payee: {
                              email_address: payee
                            },
                            shipping: shipObj
                          }]
                        });
```

and later we **approve** the order with PayPal :

```
  let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);
                        let order;
                        try {
                          order = await client.execute(request);
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                          console.error("error",err);
                          return res.sendStatus(500);
                        }
```

At this point i get `order.result.status` = **APPROVED** .

This is a live environment (the client and secret keys).
**How can you send APPROVED to developer, and give an orderID but not charge ?**
This is such a dangerous thing to do and can literally ruin businesses.

So then i found out there is a link to your order ID :

```
https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/4PE63643WC652674S
```

If you look in this page you get this :

```
"message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header."
```

Now, only god knows what this means, and this is a failur message on an **order ID** page, which mean the orderID means nothing ??

So i also check the paypal link with my client-ID (should be identical to ***my*** client id in sdk right?) :

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxx&merchant-id=xxx@yyyy.com&disable-funding=credit,card&currency=USD
```

Which seems ok and contains the right email.

Comment: You need to create the order, have the customer approve the order via the PayPal window, then you can capture the order -- it doesn't look like you're capturing it anywhere (new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(orderId))

Comment: of course i do that, there is the window, with address and price, user log in, approve the sale, then this happens. I have OrdersCreateRequest and OrdersGetRequest, so when the OrdersCaptureRequest comes ?

Comment: I don't see where you're capturing the order?

Comment: how stupid could i be. So sorry. I removed this block for some reason. Wow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may have solved the issue and that you were missing the capture step, which is a required step to commit the transaction and must always occur after approval.

Just to review the best ways to integrate, if you are doing so with API calls from a server, you'll want to set make two routes on your server, one for 'Set up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Then, the best JS customer approval flow to pair with those server-side routes is this: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server